# SignalR connect error

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I use SignalR 2.0.0 Win2012 iis8 with two environment with two different ips.
one environment service is up and second is down(purposely)
use websocket protocol.

i have the following scenario: 
When i connect to first environment and want to connect to the second.
i disconnected from first environment and try connect to second environment i get error(its correct behavior)
i try to reconnect back to the first environment but I get still the same error.

the error is "Error during negotiation request."
after refresh the browser i can connect success again to first environment.

What am i doing wrong?

this is part of my code:

```
function connect(host)
{

  var hubConnection = $.hubConnection.('');

  hubConnection.url = host;

  hubConnection.start()
               .done(open)
               .fail(error);
}
function open()
{
  console.log('login success')
}
function disconnect()
{
  var self = this,
  hubConnection = $.hubConnection("");
  console.log('disconnect ')
  hubConnection.stop(true, true);
}
function error(error)
{
  var self = this,
  hubConnection = $.hubConnection("");
  console.log('connection error ')
  if(error && hubConnection.state !== $.connection.connectionState.connected)     
   {
    .....
    .....
    //logic detemninate wich environment ip was previous 
    connect(environment ip)
   }
}
//occured when button disconnect clicked
function disconnectFromFirstEnvironmentAndConnectToSecond()
{
 disconect();
 connect(second environment ip);
}
  .....
  .....
  connect(first environment ip);
```

Comment: Add your codez so we can help

Comment: i am added the code in question.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You're not retaining your first connection reference.

Aka you create a `HubConnection` and then never capture it in a scope that can be used later; therefore when you disconnect later the connection.stop does nothing because it's not calling stop on the `HubConnection` that was originally started.

This could ultimately lead to you having too many concurrently open requests which will then not allow you to negotiate with a server hence your error.

I'd recommend fixing how you stop/start connections.  Next if the issue still occurs I'd inspect the network traffic to ensure that valid requests are being made.

Comment: sorry i dont understand can you fix that on my code.
Thank You

Comment: Hi Taylor, 
Can you attitude to my previous question?Thank you